# Is there a starts-with /contains function in xpath to search for a node name

Tags: xml, xpath

Sample XML that I use can be shown as below;

```
<Response>
      <custom_field>
         <duedate_176307 null="true"/>
         <smsalertsent_176307 null="true"/>
         <surveygizmoid_176307 null="true"/>
      </custom_field>
<Response>
```

I want to retrieve the value in which the name of the node starts with 'smsalertsent'. Is there a way to construct the xpath expression to get it done like a 'starts-with' or 'contains' kind of aproach?

Comment: That's incredibly bad XML design- realistically, the `custom_field` attribute should have an attribute like `id="176307"`, then it would be a trivial matter to find `/Response/custom_field/smsalertsent`. If you have control over the input XML, I strongly recommend changing it, or asking whoever provides it to change it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the `custom_field` element.. brain was already thinking about attributes.

Comment: To show an example: `<custom_field id="176307"><duedate null="true"/><smsalertsent null="true"/>...` Node names should be fix, so they can be defined in a format description.

Comment: Sorry I am not suppose to change the xml since it's a result of an API call.Whatever the custom field we add, in the beack end it stores along with an ID append to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
/Response/custom_field/*[starts-with(local-name(),'smsalertsent')]
```